# Parts of GUI goes black e.g. while resizing

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, gtkmm

My application uses Gtkmm and gtkglextmm. It loads pictures form HDD and shows them using OpenGL capabilities. However when I (for example) resize mainwindow some parts of GUI goes black and I don't know why. On Ubuntu this problem doesn't exist.

Here is a video illustrating what I am talking about: http://youtu.be/XGNJmddh_m4

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code, and assuming it does nothing arcane I'd attribute this to some bug in the GTK+ port for Windows itself. I suspect the doublebuffering built into GTK+ getting tangles up with the inherent doublebuffering of the composition process (Aero), and having a set a background erasure brush in the WNDCLASSEX of the windows GTK+ creates.

I'd file this as a bug with GTK+

Comment: any idea how to get around that?

Comment: @If it's a GTK+ bug, then by filing it, ideally also fixing it and submitting a patch. Could you post source code for a minimal working (= broken) example, so that I can try to reproduce it?